# Ubuntu 20.04, fail2ban bans IPs and puts them into iptables, BUT banned IPs can still connect and fail2ban log says IPs are already banned

Tags: iptables, fail2ban, ubuntu-20.04

Ubuntu 20.04. I have a huge amount of records in my /var/log/nginx/access.log that look like this:

```
85.249.25.218 - - [15/Dec/2020:08:12:15 +0300] "POST /api/v1/device/analytics HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "-" "okhttp/4.8.1"
```

I have installed fail2ban, content of my /etc/fail2ban/jail.local is:

```
[sshd]
enabled   = true
maxretry  = 3
findtime  = 1w
bantime   = 4w
protocol  = all
port      = all
banaction = iptables-allports

[nginx-botsearch]
enabled   = true
maxretry  = 3
findtime  = 1w
bantime   = 4w
protocol  = all
port      = all
logpath   = %(nginx_error_log)s
banaction = iptables-allports

[nginx-custom2]
enabled   = true
maxretry  = 3
findtime  = 1w
bantime   = 4w
protocol  = all
port      = all
logpath   = %(nginx_access_log)s
banaction = iptables-allports
```

Filter /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-custom2.conf:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>.*GET \/api\/v1\/device\/.*
            ^<HOST>.*POST \/api\/v1\/device\/.*
            ^<HOST>.*PUT \/api\/v1\/device\/.*
ignoreregex =
```

Fail2ban bans IPs that I am interested in and puts them into iptables, my fail2ban-client -v status nginx-custom2 output is:

```
Status for the jail: nginx-custom2
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 11
|  |- Total failed: 2962
|  `- File list:    /var/log/nginx/access.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 88
   |- Total banned: 88
   `- Banned IP list:   176.59.129.174 176.59.129.44 176.59.130.124 176.59.132.106 176.59.133.195 176.59.134.14 176.59.142.78 176.59.146.203 176.59.151.46 176.59.193.194 176.59.194.205 176.59.200.101 176.59.200.92 176.59.201.16 176.59.201.174 176.59.32.58 176.59.32.99 176.59.33.4 176.59.33.43 176.59.33.86 176.59.34.97 176.59.38.189 176.59.39.47 176.59.43.227 176.59.46.102 176.59.46.210 176.59.49.240 176.59.52.215 176.59.68.151 176.99.82.18 178.176.48.132 178.67.194.209 178.67.196.94 188.113.141.148 213.234.251.192 213.27.48.88 213.87.250.113 217.118.64.2 217.118.93.139 31.13.144.102 31.173.241.11 31.173.80.23 37.29.40.213 37.29.41.108 37.29.41.208 46.187.12.73 46.45.200.129 62.133.162.154 80.83.237.30 80.83.237.34 83.149.21.218 83.234.120.247 85.115.243.47 85.115.248.16 85.115.248.250 85.140.0.111 85.140.0.159 85.140.0.9 85.140.1.20 85.140.1.225 85.140.12.183 85.140.19.132 85.140.2.127 85.140.4.36 85.140.4.92 85.174.194.255 85.174.198.90 85.249.163.166 85.249.25.218 85.26.164.108 85.26.164.151 85.26.165.234 85.26.165.238 85.26.232.91 85.26.233.73 85.26.235.207 89.113.138.149 89.113.138.255 89.113.139.227 89.113.140.202 89.178.132.99 93.88.25.3 95.153.129.19 95.153.129.237 109.197.205.118 85.115.248.36 176.59.140.152 176.59.68.199
```

And iptables -L -n -v ouput is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 419 packets, 175K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
23438 6327K f2b-nginx-custom2  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
22460 6268K f2b-nginx-botsearch  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
22460 6268K f2b-sshd   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 412 packets, 60919 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain f2b-nginx-botsearch (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       87.26.121.231        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       8.129.209.71         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       47.98.190.243        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       171.244.49.242       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       157.131.240.194      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       149.129.137.131      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       128.106.166.8        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       103.76.228.45        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       103.44.245.166       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
22460 6268K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-nginx-custom2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  117  7020 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.68.199        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   58  3480 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.140.152       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   72  4320 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.115.248.36        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    7   420 REJECT     all  --  *      *       109.197.205.118      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       95.153.129.237       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       95.153.129.19        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   23  1380 REJECT     all  --  *      *       93.88.25.3           0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       89.178.132.99        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       89.113.140.202       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       89.113.139.227       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       89.113.138.255       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       89.113.138.149       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.26.235.207        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.26.233.73         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.26.232.91         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.26.165.238        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.26.165.234        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.26.164.151        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   17  1020 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.26.164.108        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   32  1920 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.249.25.218        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  189 11340 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.249.163.166       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.174.198.90        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.174.194.255       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.4.92          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.4.36          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.2.127         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   15   900 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.19.132        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.12.183        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.1.225         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.1.20          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   40  2400 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.0.9           0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.0.159         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.140.0.111         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.115.248.250       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.115.248.16        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       85.115.243.47        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       83.234.120.247       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   66  3960 REJECT     all  --  *      *       83.149.21.218        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       80.83.237.34         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       80.83.237.30         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       62.133.162.154       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       46.45.200.129        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       46.187.12.73         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       37.29.41.208         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       37.29.41.108         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       37.29.40.213         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       31.173.80.23         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   12   720 REJECT     all  --  *      *       31.173.241.11        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       31.13.144.102        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       217.118.93.139       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       217.118.64.2         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    7   420 REJECT     all  --  *      *       213.87.250.113       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    4   240 REJECT     all  --  *      *       213.27.48.88         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       213.234.251.192      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       188.113.141.148      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  210 12600 REJECT     all  --  *      *       178.67.196.94        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       178.67.194.209       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       178.176.48.132       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.99.82.18         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.68.151        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.52.215        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.49.240        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.46.210        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.46.102        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.43.227        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    7   420 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.39.47         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.38.189        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.34.97         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.33.86         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.33.43         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.33.4          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.32.99         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.32.58         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.201.174       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.201.16        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.200.92        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.200.101       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.194.205       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  102  6120 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.193.194       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.151.46        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.146.203       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.142.78        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.134.14        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.133.195       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.132.106       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.130.124       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.129.44        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       176.59.129.174       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
22460 6268K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    9   724 REJECT     all  --  *      *       110.16.95.6          0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   18  1384 REJECT     all  --  *      *       113.190.235.28       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   45  3192 REJECT     all  --  *      *       94.191.38.203        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   20  1556 REJECT     all  --  *      *       14.232.214.138       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   18  1424 REJECT     all  --  *      *       222.252.30.29        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   31  2268 REJECT     all  --  *      *       146.59.157.181       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   11   660 REJECT     all  --  *      *       110.35.79.23         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   20  1512 REJECT     all  --  *      *       190.202.32.2         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   23  1732 REJECT     all  --  *      *       190.79.227.81        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       103.127.108.96       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       103.123.246.130      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       101.36.110.215       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       101.109.245.158      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       1.245.61.144         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
21387 6197K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ispmgr_allow_ip (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ispmgr_allow_sub (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ispmgr_deny_ip (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ispmgr_deny_sub (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

BUT, I still get records in my /var/log/nginx/access.log from IPs that are already banned. Also I get a lot of records in my /var/log/fail2ban.log that look like this:

```
2020-12-15 08:23:38,156 fail2ban.actions [2803]: WARNING [nginx-custom2] 83.149.21.218 already banned
```

Please help me understand where to go from here.

Comment: maybe what you want is DROP instead of REJECT - blocktype = DROP && also established connections when fail2ban decides to ban an IP are not terminated, so if there were many requests to your server open they will need to run into timeout

Comment: You should also use an ipset banaction for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Tried restarting nginx, also changed banaction to iptables[port=”0:65535″, protocol=all, blocktype=DROP], iptables shows records like this now, so it changed to DROP: 7   420 DROP       all  --  *      *       46.45.200.129        0.0.0.0/0, but still having records in fail2ban logs: 2020-12-15 23:33:24,134 fail2ban.actions        [40290]: WARNING [nginx-custom2] 46.45.200.129 already banned, and 46.45.200.129 - - [15/Dec/2020:23:37:10 +0300] "PUT /api/v1/device/info HTTP/1.1" 405 166 "-" "okhttp/4.8.1" in my /var/log/nginx/access.log and also in nginx error log.

Comment: If you’re not set on fail2ban you could try https://github.com/DigitalRuby/ipban - it supports most Linux versions.

Answer (score 0):

I see `ufw` chains in your `iptables` output.
Could it be that your net-filter backend that `ufw` uses is a `nftables`?
If I remember me correctly the backend switch is planned for Ubuntu by 20.10, but perhaps you did change it by yourself or some service installed (in this case you should better switch to nftables banning action).

Although it would not be to false in using of low-level net-filter, but if you use ufw, what speaks against the usage of ufw-banning action in fail2ban?

And there seems to be still a ispmanager...

Anyway, I see all the chains (`ispmgr_*` and `ufw-*`) in iptables but no references to them. So either it is configured weird or something is wrong with your firewall sub-system on this system.

Is it a VM? (if yes which one?)...
Is iptables kernel module used (allowed) at all on your system?
And what exactly your ufw backend is?